# Azure CosmosDB Mongo C# Driver ReplaceOneAsync throws "Request size is too large"

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Banging my head against the wall for some time. We're using Azure CosmosDB (Mongo) to store our custom documents.
We're using the MongoDB C# driver.

It's failing at the ReplaceOnAsync below with "Request Size is Too Large".

```
    var existingEntity = await GetAll<TEntity>().Where(predicate).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (existingEntity == null)
        throw new Exception($"Mongo: No {typeof(TEntity).Name.ToLower()} document found: {predicate}");

    entity.IdDoc = existingEntity.IdDoc;
    entity.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

    var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<TEntity>().Eq(e => e.IdDoc, existingEntity.IdDoc);
    var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
    var updateRes = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, entity);
```

I have checked the size of `entity` using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity)) which returns ~528000

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#documents) the limit is 2MB, so I'm well below that.

Also been looking at [the source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/ec74978f7e827515f29cc96fba0c727828e8df7c/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCollectionBase.cs) of the driver but can't find anything obvious.

Why am I getting this error? How can I mitigate this, should I perhaps be using different UpdateOptions, or ...?

Comment: what if you insert the doc directly? same error?

Comment: @urlreader yep I had same though... Insert works! So it must be our filter.

Comment: maybe 'filter' returns more than one doc? Just a wild guess

Comment: yeah my guess as well, but that's not the case. Looks like there may be a bug in the C# MongoDB driver.

Comment: or, your driver is not the latest? I remember the limit was 512KB? I could be wrong.

Comment: Upgraded to latest, did not matter. Limit for documents is 2MB. inserting is fine; it's just the filter that causes trouble. Super annoying to debug as when I run the filter, I get only one document of ~400 KB jsonified.